# Error with tikzcd diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I am trying to make a diagram on beamer using tikzcd. I am super bad at this but still I cannot figure what am I doing wrong. I would appreciate any help. Here is the code: ( I will add an image of what I am trying to draw, if asked)

```
 \[
   \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=tiny]

  \& 
  \& I \ar[d] \ar[dd, dashed, "\epsilon", bend right=10]
  \& 
  \& \\
  1 \ar[r]  
  \& K^\times/E_m \ar[r] \ar[d]
  \&  I_m \ar[r] \ar[d] 
  \& C_m \ar[r] \ar[d, "id"] 
  \& 1  \\
  1 \ar[r] 
  \& T_m(Q) \ar[r] \ar[d]  
  \& S_m(Q) \ar[r]\ar[d] 
  \& C_m \ar[r] 
  \& 1 \\
 \& T_m(Q_\ell) \ar[r] 
 \& S_m(Q_\ell) 
 \& 
 \& \\
 \& T(Q_\ell) \ar[u] \ar[ur, dashed, "\pi_\ell"] 
 \& 
 \& 
 \&

   \end{tikzcd} 
 
 \]
```

Comment: you can not have blank lines in display math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle   I literally spent 1hr for this?...... thank you...... I ll keep the post up in case there s another one as dumb as me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some off-topic suggestion (since main problem is already solved by @DavidCarlisle comment):

- you not need to use ampersand replacement, it also work with ampersands if to frame add option `[fragile]`
- in frame is sufficient space for larger (default) distance between nodes
- bended arrows is nicer with bigger bend angle and changed position of arrow label

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Commutative diagram}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    &   & I \ar[d] \ar[dd, dashed,pos=0.4, "\epsilon" ', bend right=45]
            &   &       \\
1 \ar[r]
    & K^\times/E_m \ar[r] \ar[d]
        &  I_m \ar[r] \ar[d]
            & C_m \ar[r] \ar[d, "id"]
                & 1     \\
1 \ar[r]
    & T_m(Q) \ar[r] \ar[d]
        & S_m(Q) \ar[r]\ar[d]
            & C_m \ar[r]
                & 1     \\
    & T_m(Q_\ell) \ar[r]
        & S_m(Q_\ell)
            &   &       \\
    & T(Q_\ell) \ar[u] \ar[ur, dashed, "\pi_\ell"]
        &   &   &
   \end{tikzcd}
 \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]